# Meteor Mailgun response to emails not going to "from" address

Tags: meteor, smtp, mailgun

I have the following Meteor code, with Meteor's default Mailgun SMTP settings:

```
   Email.send({
      to: "customer@gmail.com,
      from: "company@gmail.com",
      replyTo: "company@gmail.com",
      subject: 'Test',
      text: "Test"
    });
```

The email sends fine, but when the customer clicks "reply" in Gmail, it replies to "customer@gmail.com" instead of "company@gmail.com".

Comment: For anyone with this problem, it may be related to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57001/force-gmail-to-always-reply-to-sender-not-to-myself/59059#59059

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not hitting "reply all" instead of "reply".

I have just tested and it's working as expected on my end with the latest meteor and the email module.

Best,