# Meteor mailgun emails - replies not going to sender address

Tags: email, smtp, mailgun, meteor-accounts, email-headers

I've got a Meteor app using the `useraccounts:core` package for users, and my own Mailgun account configured for `MAIL_URL`; I've also configured the `from` address to be `"MYNAME <me@domain.com>"`.

When a user signs up, a verification email is sent just fine. **The problem is that when the user hits "reply", it replies to THEIR address not MY address**.

I have no idea what the problem could be, or whether it lies with Meteor, Mailgun, or Gmail.

Regarding Gmail: I viewed the exact same email on a different platform and the reply worked as expected (going to the right address).

*What I've tried:*

- When I remove any customisation like setting the `from` address, it reverts to the default meteor email (no-reply@meteor.com) and the reply works as expected
- When I do a manual `Email.send(to, from, etc.)`, the reply works as expected
- I tried setting the `replyTo` header - `Accounts.emailTemplates.headers = {replyTo : "test@killer.football"}` - no effect

With all this, I still can't diagnose where the problem is happening. It looks like it's limited to gmail, but only in some cases (where `from` is set). Any help much appreciated.

Finally, this may well be a duplicate of [Meteor Mailgun response to emails not going to "from" address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224282/meteor-mailgun-response-to-emails-not-going-to-from-address/26330898#26330898) but I'm posting as a separate question because there's just not enough information over there to be sure, and they hadn't tried the things I've tried.

Comment: It looks very much like the problem is with gmail settings, a la http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57001/force-gmail-to-always-reply-to-sender-not-to-myself/59059#59059. HOWEVER, the solution there isn't helping me, so I'll keep searching and post here if I find a fix